# How to show up label more than one properties of a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling

How to show a label that includes more than one properties of a shapefile on the layers, let say I'd like to show up to properties of a shapefile in ArcInfo / ArcGIS 10.0.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the label [expression builder](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00s800000027000000.htm) to create a label that incorporates any field of the feature. See the link provided or search l[abeling tag](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) for examples

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much HDunn ,,, :D, I have tried as your saying and it works !  :D

Comment: If it does, mark as solved please

Answer (score 0):

Ghetto method would be to add two copies of the shapefile, add a different label system for each, and then turn the dissolve on one up to 100%.